# Guzzle async POST requests not being sent

Tags: php, asynchronous, php-7.1, guzzle

I'm trying to make 4 async search calls (POST HTTP request) to search 4 database tables at the same time, then wait for all of them to finish (asynchronously), combine the results and return them to the user.

Here is my code:

```
public static function async_search($search_words)
{
    $curl = new CurlMultiHandler();
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://mytestapi.com/',
        'timeout' => 0,
    ]);

    $finished_promisesArr = array(
        'search1' => 0,
        'search2' => 0,
        'search3' => 0,
        'search4' => 0,
    );

    $bodyArr = array(
        'search_words' => $search_words,
    );

    $search1_promise = $client->requestAsync('POST', 'search1', array(
        'form_params' => $bodyArr,
    ))->then(
        function(ResponseInterface $response) {
            echo 'got response';
            $finished_promisesArr['search1'] = 1;
        },
        function (RequestException $e) {
            $finished_promisesArr['search1'] = 1;
        }
    );

    $search2_promise = $client->requestAsync('POST', 'search2', array(
        'form_params' => $bodyArr,
    ))->then(
        function(ResponseInterface $response) {
            $finished_promisesArr['search2'] = 1;
        },
        function (RequestException $e) {
            $finished_promisesArr['search2'] = 1;
        }
    );

    $search3_promise = $client->requestAsync('POST', 'searchCompanies', array(
        'form_params' => $bodyArr,
    ))->then(
        function(ResponseInterface $response) {
            $finished_promisesArr['search3'] = 1;
        },
        function (RequestException $e) {
            $finished_promisesArr['search3'] = 1;
        }
    );

    $search4_promise = $client->requestAsync('POST', 'searchCompaniesByIndustries', array(
        'form_params' => $bodyArr,
    ))->then(
        function(ResponseInterface $response) {
            $finished_promisesArr['search4'] = 1;
        },
        function (RequestException $e) {
            $finished_promisesArr['search4'] = 1;
        }
    );

    $promisesAggregate = GuzzleHttp\Promise\all([$search1_promise, $search2_promise, $search3_promise, $search4_promise]);
    foreach ($promisesAggregate as $agg) {
        $curl->tick();
    }

    $keep_running = true;
    while ($keep_running) {
        $all_processes_finished = true;
        foreach ($finished_promisesArr as $promise => $status) {
            if (!$status) {
                $all_processes_finished = false;
            }
        }

        if ($all_processes_finished) {
            $keep_running = false;
        }
    }

    return array();
}
```

Please ignore the empty array in the result and the fact that I'm not doing anything with the response.
I've got logs on the server methods and they're not even being called, and the loop continues to run infinitely.

Note that when I use the `request` method instead of `requestAsync` I do get the correct result.

Any ideas here?

Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

Just call `$promisesAggregate->wait()` after you get it from `GuzzleHttp\Promise\all` function.

It means the same as your code, but does it right (your wait code calls `->tick()` only once and this is the mistake).

Comment: But then I lose the purpose behind asynchronous requests by waiting for each one to finish, don't I?

Comment: No, you create 4 requests, get (immediately) promises from each and wait for all of them to finish.

Comment: So you wait when all of them will be done. But they all are executed simultaneously.